# libgphoto2 and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2019

I'm new to C++ and right now struggling with including a external library such as gphoto2. That being said I have no idea how to include it in Visual Studio 2019.

So, how do I include https://github.com/gphoto/libgphoto2 properly?

Thanks

Comment: From the link: _"...libgphoto2 should compile and run on pretty much all Unix-like platforms. libgphoto2 has not (yet?) been ported to any operating system from __MicroSoft__...."_  So are you cross-compiling and if so to what platform?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/gphoto/gphoto2/issues/85

Comment: The final application will run on linux, right now I'm debugging over ssh. I know the line from the github page, but (if I understood C right) it should be somehow possible to import the library on Windows too without rewriting it, right?

Answer (score 2):

Use the msvc folder found here: https://github.com/vividos/RemotePhotoTool/tree/master/build